# kill background process spawn in codeship

Tags: bash, process, background

To [kill background process inside Codeship](https://documentation.codeship.com/basic/continuous-integration/run-a-command-in-the-background/) we need to use following command:

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup bash -c "YOUR_COMMAND 2>&1 &"
```

The `bash -c` is needed in codeship but because this killing `YOUR_COMMAND` fails when storing it inside variable using `PID_COMMAND=$!`. It could be I am missing/doing something (wrong). But I have googled a lot and could not find correct answer so I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: Did you already create a ticket on our helpdesk at https://helpdesk.codeship.com? And to get a better understanding of the question, why do you want to kill the background process. The VM is shutdown and destroyed after the build so in most cases cleanup is unnecessary.

Comment: I have not yet created a ticket. I spawn a background process but it does not load correctly sometimes. When I respawn it does work. I have already created an implementation that works although not perfect because I do use killall instead of kill specific PID so I could possible kill extra processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW:

I started a flask app with: `flask run &`

To kill the background process, I use pgrep & kill to find and terminate the flask instance:

```
kill $(pgrep -f flask)
```

Replace 'flask' with whatever name your command/program was